# After inserting new post with wp_insert_post() the post is not visble to WP_Query, but the same WP_Query works for post inserted from wp-admin panel

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, wp-admin, post-meta

Made s script that under certain conditions adds a new custom post to the database. All works fine. But there is a flow. After writing the post to the database with my script I can not extract it with WP_Query. If I add posts directly from the wp-admin panel all wokrs fine. But is I add post with my script I can not extract them with WP_Query. The new added post appears in the posts list in the wp-admin panel with all the needed values, all is cool but not visible to WP_Query. It only becomes visible after I change any of the post's custom fields in the wp-admin panel and press the Update button. After refereshing the page all starts to work perfectly.

[image]

The new post seems to be published and I can even extract specific fields from it when I list all the available posts of this type.

[image]

The query. I know for a fact that the query works fine because it works for the posts I ppublish directly from the wp-admin panel.
[image]

Comment: Have you compared the value of `player_relation` before you manually update the post and after? When you insert the post you're saving a `WP_Post` object as the value, but that's not what you're querying for, and it's not how ACF stores Relationship field values. You need to make sure you're inserting the value in the expected format.

Comment: Could you please post the actual code samples rather than screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! I changed the a field type and changed the query conditions.

Comment: Consider adding the working code into the answer so future users that have the same problem can use your code to fix it.